# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz" but libz exists

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit

While making my program on Redhat based linux (amd64), I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Searching internet reveals that I have t install zlib 32bit version. A quick search shows that I have that package

```
[root@localhost trunk]# find / -name libz*
/lib64/libz.so.1
/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
/lib/libz.so.1
/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
/usr/lib64/libz.so
/usr/lib64/purple-2/libzephyr.so
/usr/lib64/libzip.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libzip.so.1
```

As you can see both `/lib` and `/lib64` contain the libz file. Next I tried to find the ldd search path and it shows that both 32 bit and 64 bit folders are included

```
[root@localhost trunk]# ldconfig -v | grep -v ^$'\t'
/usr/lib64/ctapi:
/usr/lib64/mysql:
/usr/lib64/tcl8.5/tclx8.4:
/usr/lib64/xulrunner-2:
/lib:
/lib64:
/usr/lib:
/usr/lib64:
/lib/i686: (hwcap: 0x0008000000000000)
/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)  
/usr/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib64/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/lib/i686/nosegneg: (hwcap: 0x0028000000000000)
```

SO I wonder why still I get that error!!!!

**UPDATE**

I installed `zlib-devel` (both i686 and x86_64) and here is the confirmation

```
 [root@localhost trunk]# yum list zlib-devel
 Installed Packages
 zlib-devel.i686     1.2.3-27.el6             @sl
 zlib-devel.x86_64   1.2.3-27.el6             @sl
```

However still I get the same error.

**UPDATE 2**

After fixing the incorrect symbolic link, I now have

```
[root@localhost trunk]# ls -l /lib/libz.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    18 Feb 23 22:58 /lib/libz.so -> /usr/lib64/libz.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    13 Feb 18 12:06 /lib/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 75332 Dec 10  2011 /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
```

But error still exists

**SOLUTION**

**SOLUTION**

I found that I have to install static libraries. Don't know why Makefile searches for static libraries! Please refer to my comments for the name of packages.

Thanks [fuero](https://serverfault.com/users/13357/fuero) for help

Comment: If an answer helped you resolve your issue, you should indicate so by upvoting and accepting it. This also indicates to the system, and community, that the matter has been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `zlib-devel` or add a `libz.so` symlink to the lib directories.

`yum list` lists *ALL* packages, not just the installed ones. To find out whether it's installed, try this:

```
yum list installed | grep zlib
```

This is from a RHEL 6.3 reference system:

```
# rpm -ql zlib-devel
/usr/include/zconf.h
/usr/include/zlib.h
/usr/lib64/libz.so                  <---- the symlink I mentioned
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/README
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/algorithm.txt
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/example.c
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/minigzip.c
/usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
# rpm -ql zlib-devel.i686
/usr/include/zconf.h
/usr/include/zlib.h
/usr/lib/libz.so                    <---- the symlink I mentioned
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/README
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/algorithm.txt
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/example.c
/usr/share/doc/zlib-devel-1.2.3/minigzip.c
/usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
```

What the symlinks point to:

```
# ls /usr/lib/libz.so -lhA
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 Feb 23 20:32 /usr/lib/libz.so -> ../../lib/libz.so.1.2.3
# ls /usr/lib64/libz.so -lhA
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 Feb 23 20:24 /usr/lib64/libz.so -> ../../lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
```

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: I think a wrong path is confusing `ld`. How can I find that?

Comment: another update. don't forget to run `ldconfig`. Perhaps sharing how you call the compiler helps.

Comment: OK. The problem with `-lz` will be solved by installing static version of zlib named `zlib-static`. Now I am getting some other `-l` errors like `-lm` and that will be solved by installing `glibc-static`. I don't know why the program searches for static librsries

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone - my issue was that `cmake` was running `/usr/bin/g++ -static-libstdc++` which caused the error output: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++`.

The fix (on RHEL/CentOS) was to run `sudo yum install libstdc++-static.x86_64` since it was looking for the static lib.

Comment: It did help me, thank you :-)